# IIS7/8 and .asmx/<methodname> giving 404

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp.net-3.5, iis-8

Getting an issue with a .net 3.5 app deployed to IIS 7 (or 8). For some reason it is not able to resolve asmx webservice requests with the method name. E.g.

```
webservice.asmx/method
```

What handler do I need for this? I thought isapi.dll would take care of requests like that??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out adding a wildcard script mapping with isapi.dll (of the appropriate .net version) solves the issue.

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way of doing it (performance issues? It's in a dev environment so not crucial at the moment), any other approaches are welcome!